# IntelliJ "Project level changed:

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8

I have recently updated jdk to 1.8.0.
I also changed the `Default Project Structure` in IntelliJ to use language level 8 and jdk1.8.0.

However, now I keep getting the Dialog

> Language level changes will take effect on project reload.
>   Would you like to reload project "sbApp" now?

Even when I click "Yes", the project reloads and again displays the same dialog.

I think I missed some setting.

Comment: I have added v4, v13 and gson dependencies using maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by using [jdk8 with lambda support](https://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) which is available as a separate download.