# Android Studio: Getting Message on project load "Language level changes wil take effect on project reload..."

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep getting this message on project loads. "Language level changes wil take effect on project reload.  Would you like to reload project now?"

I did some search but nothing concrete.  it seems to suggest something with the SDK but no one seems to state concrete solution.

Please advise on a solution on this.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677377/intellij-project-level-changed)

Comment: it's because the android SDK now supports Java 7 syntax, if I know correctly. Just reload the project and you'll be fine!

Comment: i am looking to fix the situation where message doesn't show up anymore